# Dynamic array in C++ for dynamic programming

Tags: c++

I was solving a dynamic programming problem. The problem is to decompose an integer into sum of square numbers, using terms as few as possible. A standard DP problem and I come up with a program:

```
vector<int> decompose(int num){
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> mymap;
int dp[num+1];
for(int i=0; i <= num; i++){
    dp[i] = i;
}
int upbound = sqrt(num)+1;
for(int i=1; i <= upbound; i++){
    int sq = i*i;
    for(int j=0 ; j+sq <= num; j++){
        if(dp[j]+1 < dp[j+sq]){
            dp[j+sq] = dp[j]+1;
            if(mymap.find(j)!=mymap.end()){
                mymap[j+sq] = mymap[j];
                mymap[j+sq].push_back(sq);                    
            }
            else{
                 vector<int> tmp(1, sq);
                 mymap[j+sq] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < mymap[num].size(); i++){
    sum += mymap[num][i];
}
for(int i = 0; i < num - sum; i++){
    mymap[num].insert(mymap[num].begin(), 1);
}
return mymap[num];
```

}

I test it a little bit and the code works. Below are some test results:

```
num: 14, decompose as: 1 4 9 
num: 13, decompose as: 4 9 
num: 12, decompose as: 4 4 4
```

Then I try to replace the dp array using dynamic array. The reason to do so is that in some OJ sites, the stack space is limited.

Specifically, what I did is to change line 3 to

```
int *dp = new int(num+1);
```

and add

```
delete [] dp;
```

before returning the result.

However, my code does not work any more after the change. The change does not affect the algorithm itself. I guess the memory of the dynamic array I created was destroyed in the for loop. But I could not understand where exactly the problem came.

Comment: Why not just make `dp` a `std::vector<int>` ?

Comment: @paul R,  std::vector<int> will definitely work. I just couldn't understand why changing to dynamic array will fail the whole program.

Comment: Well it should work, but you may have some other bug. Try running under valgrind perhaps to see if you have any memory-related bugs. In general though you should not be using raw arrays - std::vector would be a better idea.

Comment: `int *dp = new int[num + 1]` is the correct way.

Comment: Change the parentheses: int *dp = new int[num+1];

Comment: thanks, IrineK and Akash Pradhan. This is embarrassing ..

Comment: As a side note, your original `int dp[num+1];` is not standard C++ when `num` is not a constant expression (supported in C99 and as a compiler extension in some C++ compilers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is exactly in the line where you define your array:
`int *dp = new int(num+1);` This means you create a pointer to integer value, e.g. `int`, initialized to `num+1` which is **not** what you want. To create an array you need to use the brackets `[]` instead.

`int *dp = new int[num+1];`

This creates an array of `int` elements with size `num+1`.

Comment: If you problem is solved you should accept this answer so that we lower the number of unanswered Q/A.

Comment: done. sorry, I am a newbie here so it take me a while to figure out how to accept your answer.